# How to make Microsoft Teams display line breaks of Markdown .md file?

Tags: markdown, microsoft-teams, line-breaks

how do I make Microsoft Teams display line breaks of Markdown .md file?

Didn't help:

1. Adding two or more spaces and typing return;
2. "nbsp;"
3. "< /br>"

P.S. I have to mention I'm interested in line breaks for list items

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Question resolved, method 1: "Adding two or more spaces and typing return;" works, the problem was that the file was cached, so uploading a new version above the old didn't represent the changes; I had to delete the file and reupload to see the latest version.